# странности с массивами PHP

Tags: php

Массив ведет себя по другому в цикле и вне цикла. Делаю что то типа сайта новостей, требуется вывести последние записи с рубрик, но не выводится так как массивы вне цикла ведут себя как переменная, тоесть индекс=0 есть, а индекс 1,2,3 уже ошибка,хотя внутри цикла все индексы работают:

```
$comand="SHOW TABLES FROM basename";
$result=mysql_query($comand)or die(mysql_error());
$count=array();

while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $i=0;
    $count[$i]=$row[0];
    echo  $row[0]."<br>";
    $i++;
}
echo $count[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

Я в пхп не особо разбираюсь, но `$i=0` явно нужно вынести за пределы `while` иначе зачем инкремент и тогда, вероятно, ваш цикл заработает.

Comment: да, все норм, заработало